# Vaadin How to arrange redirection through the tabs in tabsheet?

Tags: java, tabs, vaadin

Does anybody knows how to resolve my issue. 
I have a TabSheet with 4 tabs. I need,  when ever file is uploaded, to redirect the user to the second tab. My code:

```
   //create tabsheet with 4 tabs    
private void createTabs() {
TabSheet tabs = new TabSheet();
FirstTab firstTab = new FirstTab();
tabs.addTab(firstTab, "FirstTab");
SecondTab secondTab = new SecondTab();
tabs.addTab(secondTab, "SecondTab");
ThirdTab thirdTab = new ThirdTab();
tabs.addTab(thirdTab, "ThirdTab");
FourthTab fourthTab = new FourthTab();
tabs.addTab(fourthTab, "FourthTab");    
vertLayout.addComponent(tabs);
}

//create upload button
    private Button uploadButton() { 
    Button uploadFile = new Button("Upload");
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(new UploadFileWindow());
    return uploadFile;    
      }
```

Thanks for support!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it was a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vaadin TabSheet component has a method to set the selected tab.

In your code (after the upload is done) just add:

```
tabs.setSelectedTab(fourthTab);
```

[Here is the corresponding documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#setSelectedTab-com.vaadin.ui.Component-).